# Put_metric_alarm - How to use comparison operator with "Equal to Threshold" in AWS - Python Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Currently, I can see only below possible values for the Comparision parameter, is it possible for EqualToThreshold to be used as comparison operator?

```
GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
GreaterThanThreshold
LessThanThreshold
LessThanOrEqualToThreshold
LessThanLowerOrGreaterThanUpperThreshold
LessThanLowerThreshold
GreaterThanUpperThreshold
```

Suppose I want to create an alarm whenever the threshold value **equals 0**, but I do not see the "Equal" option. Is there any other work around we can use to make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Equal`, but in your case you could use:

```
LessThanOrEqualToThreshold of 0
```

instead of `Equal` to 0.